# Equation of path traced by a charged particle in time varying magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

[image]Is there anyway to figure out the equation for trajectory of a charged particle in a magnetic field(which varies with time) increasing inside the plane of the screen, the particle is outside the magnetic field in order to simplify the situation, The induced electric field affects it but the actual   magnetic field doesn't. I don't have much knowledge about multivariable calculus as I'm in high school but I tried to figure out an equation by splitting everything in two components, one parallel to x-axis and the other parallel to y and used theta as a variable, theta being the angle made by the position vector of the particle with the +y-axis but I always ended up with differential equations having 3 or more variables.
The main equation that I used was

acceleration of charged particle along x axis
$$a(x)=eq\frac{cos(\theta)}{2\pi R}$$
$R$ being the distance of the particle from the center of the circular origin and also the origin
Also wrote acceleration along y-axis and tried to solve these equations along with 2 more, but nonetheless wasn't able to get them down to 2 variables, How can we obtain the equation of the path followed by the particle, maybe in parametric co-ordinates such as time
For initial condition we can say that the particle is located on the surface of the circular region.

After trying to solve this for a long time, the repeated result kept on popping up(I'm not sure if this is correct though)

$$
\frac{d^2x/dt^2}{d^2y/dt^2}=\frac{-y(t)}{x(t)}
$$

Where t=time is a parameter and x and y are the co-ordinates of the charged particle, I tried to guess a few functions of t which would satisfy this condition but the one function that I found which satisfied it was x(t)=e^t
y(t)=e^it which is a complex function, I'm not sure if there's any real function that can satisfy this differential
equation.

Comment: Can you please describe your problem more clearly - there are some parts which seem to be in contradiction. I would suggest you clearly separate the problem statement with your (attempted) solution.